# Finding the text inside this element

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, addeventlistener

I'm looking to make a fairly simple operation: you click on an `li`, you get the text inside, using JavaScript (not JQuery). What I can't figure out (or find out) is how to get the `innerHTML`.

```
function enable() {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('refine-menu-li')) {
      var selected = this.innerHTML;
      console.log('stuff'); // Working
      console.log(selected); // Not working
    } 
  });
}
```

Is the problem that I am using `class` and so require a `for`-loop? Or is `this` a foolish thing to try and use?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think the `this` refers to? Because in this case, it refers to the `this` context of the `enable()` function.

Comment: "you click on an li" — List items are not interactive controls. People using keyboard navigation can't select them. People using screen readers can't select them. It is possible to have round these issues, but there is a simpler solution: **Use a button** (which can be inside the list item and can have any CSS you like applied to it) if you want the user to click on something that isn't a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, without using an arrow function:

```js
 document.getElementById("js-list")
         .addEventListener("click",function(e) {
            if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
              console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
            }
         });
```

```html
<ul id="js-list">
   <li>value1</li>
   <li>value2</li>
   <li>value3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions capture `this` from the context they are declared in.

`this.innerHTML` is not the `innerHTML` you are looking for.

You probably want `e.target.innerHTML`.

---

If you weren't using an arrow function, then `this` will wouldn't be the value you wanted. Event handlers are called in the context of the element they are bound to (`document` in this case), not the element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function enable() {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    
    var current = e.target;
    
    if (e.target.classList.contains('refine-menu-li')) {
      var selected = current.innerHTML;
      console.log('stuff'); // Working
      console.log(selected); // Not working
    } 
  });
}

enable();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='refine-menu-li a'>1 </li>
  <li class='refine-menu-li b '>2</li>
  <li class='refine-menu-li c '>3</li>
  <li class='refine-menu-li d'>4</li>
</ul>
```